# finding the line segment?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> let  $a$ and $b$ belong $\mathbb R$. If $P(x,y)$ is the point  in the plane, define $f(P)= ax + by$. let the  line segment $AB$ bisect the line segment $CD$.If $f(A)=5$ , $f(B)=5$ and $f(C)= 10$ , find $f(D).$

I was trying this   question that  AB bisect the  CD that mean  it  mean  they have equal sides and  their  mid point  have  same  coordinates. But my  answer is  f(A)= f(B)=5 and  f(C)= f(D) = 10 and my answer  is  f(D)=10
Is my answer is correct or not, im not sure  i have only used my own logic

if anbody help me i  would be very thankful to him

Answer (score 0):

$f(D)=0$. I assume the line segments bisect each other.

Given:
$$f(A)=aa_1+ba_2=5$$
$$f(B)=ab_1+bb_2=5$$
$$f(C)=ac_1+bc_2=10$$
$$f(D)=ad_1+bd_2=?$$
Note:
$$\frac{f(A)+f(B)}{2}=5$$
$$\frac{f(C)+f(D)}{2}=\frac{f(A)+f(B)}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{10+f(D)}{2}=5 \Rightarrow f(D)=0.$$

Comment: thanks  a lot and love u @farruhota

Answer (score 0):

An equation of $AB$ it's $ax+by=5$.

Thus, $$a\cdot\frac{x_C+x_D}{2}+b\cdot\frac{y_C+y_D}{2}=5$$ or
$$10+f(D)=10$$ or
$$f(D)=0$$.

Comment: @legoh legoh You are welcome!